# Leading Spaces in SAS input

Tags: input, tabs, sas, spaces

I am reading a plain text file into SAS that is tab-delimited. One variable is a character with leading spaces. How do I read in the variable starting from the first character (ignoring the leading spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `$CHAR.` informat is being used to read the variable.

Let's create a sample tab delimited file with two fields, the second of which has leading spaces.

```
filename tabx temp;
data _null_;
  file tabx ;
  put '1' '09'x '  ABC';
run;
```

And now let's read it back in.

```
data test;
  infile tabx dsd dlm='09'x ;
  length id 8 name $20 ;
  informat name $char. ;
  input id name ;
run;
```